# Getting grails view as string?

Tags: grails, view, grails-controller

Can I get grails view as string in grails ?

I have one view on location `"/template/product.gsp"` inside view folder. I can render it using

```
render (view: "/template/product", model: [product: Product.get(1)])
```

It's working without any problem, But what I need is to get the rendering content as string. Because I need to pass it vertical response for creating email with the rendering data.

Please help me.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you try this
myTemplateString=g.render(template: "product", model:[product: Product.get(1)])

Comment: @AnantKolvankar : ok i will try...

Comment: @AnantKolvankar  :yup it's working ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `render` method of [PageRenderer](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/api/grails/gsp/PageRenderer.html#render(java.util.Map)) class, like

```
PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

def someMethodOrAction(){
    groovyPageRenderer.render(view: 'myView', model: someParamsIfAny)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this

`myTemplateString=g.render(template: "product", model:[product: Product.get(1)])`